# Android Compose - How to make Image show under Statusbar?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I just started with Jetpack Compose. My app has many screens, it shows StatusBar with color, which is defined in the theme, but on some screens, I want to make StatusBar color is transparent and Image show under StatusBar.

Please guide me step by step.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: is your question how to show an `image under status bar` or how to change status bar `color` to transparent dynamically on a particular screen ?

Comment: to change the color check also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67579824/compose-custom-materialtheme-colors-not-working/67580759#67580759

Answer (score 11):

Just write this line before setContent

```
  window.setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
    )
```

Comment: This only works with some devices and it also extends the background under the device's bottom navigation, which was not the question

Answer (score 2):

Firstly in your res > theme remove action bar;

```
<style name="Theme.app_android" 
parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Then call your composable in MainActivity, setting WindowCompat before as shown below

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
     setContent {
     App()
    }
  }
}
```

Then using the ProvideWindowInsets function to remember a systemUiController that's called inside a SideEffect function that sets the system status bar to transparent

```
@Composable
fun App() {
    AppTheme {
        ProvideWindowInsets {
        val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()

        SideEffect {
            systemUiController.setSystemBarsColor(Color.Transparent, 
            darkIcons = false)
        }

        val navController = rememberNavController()
        val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
        val navBackStackEntry by 
        navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
        val currentRoute = navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route

        Scaffold() { innerPadding ->
            Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)) {
                NavGraph(navController = navController)
               }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

If you clone the compose samples from here https://github.com/android/compose-samples they show you this way to implement it

Answer (score 2):

Before `setContent{}` on `Activity` `onCreate()` do:

```
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
```

Comment: This solution is also used by Jetcaster sample app
https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/Jetcaster/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetcaster/ui/MainActivity.kt

Comment: Jetcaster sample app has migrate from `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)` to `enableEdgeToEdge()`

Answer (score 0):

Add `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)` in your Activity  `onCreate`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
        ...
}
```

Then add `WindowInsets.navigationBars` in your `Scaffold` to prevent the bottom parts overlap with the navigationbars

```
Scaffold(
    contentWindowInsets = WindowInsets.navigationBars
)
```